# How do I save IEx history?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

With IEx (Elixir's REPL), I'd like to be able to save my command history.

For example:

I can open up a new IEx session and execute a command. After executing the command I can press the up arrow and have my last-command pre-populated. After closing IEx and re-opening, I'd like to have access to my last commands.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**For Erlang/OTP 20**

This is built-in (from https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-shell-history)

> From Erlang/OTP 20, it is possible to get shell history by passing
>   some flags that enable it in the VM. This can be done on a per-need
>   basis when starting IEx:
>
> `iex --erl "-kernel shell_history enabled"`
>
> If you would rather enable
>   it on your system as a whole, you can use the `ERL_AFLAGS` environment
>   variable and make sure that it is set accordingly on your
>   terminal/shell configuration.
>
> On Linux [and macOS]:
>
> `export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled"`
>
> On Windows:
>
> `set ERL_AFLAGS "-kernel shell_history enabled"`

To show where the history file is located, run the following code from erl (Mac OS example value shown):

```
1> filename:basedir(user_cache, "erlang-history")
"/Users/your.username/Library/Caches/erlang-history"
```

To set the file to a different location, use the `shell_history_path /path/to/history-file` [option from the erlang docs (compatible with Elixir/iex)](https://erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html):

```
export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history_path '\"$HOME/.erlang-history\"'"
```

---

**For Erlang/OTP 19 and below**

Try using https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history

```
> git clone https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history.git
> cd erlang-history
> sudo make install    # may not need sudo depending on installation
```

Comment: Just tried this out and it seems that history is not written correctly in some cases when exiting IEx by hitting `Ctrl`+`C` twice, which many people do. I had no problems when always terminating IEx with `Ctrl`+`G` `Q` `Enter` though, which is a cleaner way to exit IEx anyway.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes it has to do with how fast you quit. Might be a file write race condition of sorts?

Comment: Haha maybe it just takes longer to hit this insane key combo so I'm less likely to run into the problem ;-)

Comment: On MacOS you have to create an empty history file, otherwise it does not work: $ touch ~/.iex_history

Comment: what's the advantage of `ctrl-G Q enter` over `ctrl-C a enter`?

Comment: @jaydel I guess it's the same as shutting down your computer by pressing the power button, vs using the "shut down" function of your OS: state is saved, doesn't end with an error etc.

Comment: AFAIC `iex --erl "-kernel shell_history enabled"` works, but `ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled"` as environment variable doesn't, within a docker. If anyone has an idea, I'd be happy but I can live without it.

Comment: @AndreiSura On Linux too. So it looks like the file `~/.iex_history` has to exist.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger hello two years later. I've added a docker compose example.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know if things changed at some point, but I found the above did not work. After looking at the man page for iex, I noticed that it needed to be

```
export ELIXIR_ERL_OPTIONS="-kernel shell_history enabled"
```

(note the additional ELIXIR). Perhaps the original solution was cogent was relevant for erl (I found it worked for that), but iex added the qualifier? Since the original question *was* for iex though, figured it should be updated.

Comment: Can confirm the accepted answer no longer works and the above did.
Worth noting  (as others mentioned) that if you use ctrl+c to quit (as I do), you'll need to use ctrl + g following by q and enter

Comment: I can also confirm it and as of now the history is retained even when I use ctrl+c ctrl+c to exit on my Mac.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using the oh-my-zsh, so I put on the `vim ~/.zshrc`:

```
# Enable history in IEX through Erlang(OTP)
export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled"
```

then `source  ~/.zshrc` and now always load. Thank's @loeschg.

Answer (score 3):

For docker compose, you will need to create a volume to save the history, and tell Erlang where it is via `-kernel shell_history_path`. The path needs to be an Erlang term, so make sure it's `'"tripple quoted"'`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  elixir:
    environment:
      ERL_AFLAGS: -kernel shell_history enabled -kernel shell_history_path '"/somewhere/sensible"'
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: shell_history
        target: /somewhere/sensible

volumes:
  shell_history:
```